# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError while using devise for registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, strong-parameters

I am using devise to register my users. I am customizing the create action of the registration controller, however whenever I try to create any new user it is refused and I get the mentioned error. I know I have to permit the params needed and I do so I don't understand why I keep getting the error. Below are my trials thus far.

```
#user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
    belongs_to :country
    #rest of the code
end

## Custom registeration controller
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            sign_in(@user, bypass: true)
            redirect_to user_employee_steps_path(@user),
    notice: 'A confirmation email was sent to your email, please complete your profile
            and confirm your account to start looking for potential employees'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end

#new.html.erb the view for the registration sign up
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :dob, "Birthday" %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :dob, start_year: 1900, end_year: Time.now.year - 18 %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :country_id, "Country" %><br />
    <%= f.select :country_id, Country.order(name: :asc).collect { |country| [country.name, country.id] }, prompt: 'Select your country' %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :city %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :city %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>

#application controller where I permit params for sign up
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        puts '%' * 30
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:first_name, :last_name, :country_id, :city, :dob]
        puts devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)
        puts '%' * 30
    end
end
```

Now whenever I create a new user I get the mentioned error in the title, and the result of the puts statement that's being published is as follows:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
email
password
password_confirmation
first_name
last_name
country_id
city
dob
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

which means that the method configure_permitted_parameters was called correctly, and the required params should be already there, so I do not understand where the problem might be?! I am really stuck on this and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

Instead, maybe you should try

```
@user = User.new sign_up_params
```

If you wish to understand better why, read more about strong parameters and Rails 4.
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Or to stick with the devise handling you can also write

```
build_resource sign_up_params
```

And then the resource variable will give you access to your user that you can save, etc...

Comment: Is the sign_up_params helper method available from devise? If so what other helpers are available (Or how can I find out about them?).

Comment: The sign_up_params is available ! You can use it directly in your controller.

Comment: I tried it and it is working thank you, my question was how was it available? was it a method provided via devise, and if so are there more helper methods such as this one that are provided and how can I learn about them?

Comment: I just looked at this file :
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

@thresh: Though this is not 100% parallel to your code, the error is similar, and this fix to use "strong parameters" as @Uelb suggests might help.

I got a similar error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
```

And the offending line of code:

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  ...    
  def confirm
    ...
    if resource.update_attributes(params[resource_name].except(:confirmation_token))
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

I solved it by changing the code to use "strong parameters" as follows:

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  ...    
  def confirm
    ...
    if resource.update_attributes(resource_params)
      ...
    end
  end

  private

  def resource_params
    params[resource_name].except(:confirmation_token).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Relevant versions:

- devise (3.5.10)
- Rails 4.2.11.1
- protected_attributes (1.1.4)